# What is the meaning of the "one mind" in the awakening of faith?

Tags: mahayana, comparative-religion, mind

You can read that shastra [here](http://www.thezensite.com/ZenTeachings/Translations/Awakening_of_faith.html). I'm quite fond of it, though I don't have my own meditation practice.

If I had to narrow the question down, I'd ask if it contains different practices, of different sentient beings. Not absolutely sure that makes sense, though. I like the idea of it substituting for 'heaven' on those grounds, of others.

Comment: i found [this](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/583883) and will read it, and post an answer in the next few days, if no-one else does.

Answer (score 1):

'One mind' means reality, the reality which is in front of you now and which you are part of. It manifests in two ways - as the absolute, when you don't concieve in terms of self and others; and the phenomenal, when you do.

Comment: thanks for the reply, gavin. should i leave one about Wonhyo? i'm not sure

Comment: Yes, that's what the site is for :) I will be interested to find out what it means...